# How to download asset images in react native?

Tags: react-native, imagedownload

I'm new to react native. I would like to know how to download an asset image, which is an image bundled in source code and is accessible via `require('./images/test.png')` but it doesn't have a url. It seems 'rn-fetch-blob' needs to perform a fetch request which require an image url to download the image. But my image is a bundled image. So I'm blocked here.

It would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this image?

Comment: I wanted to download this image into user CAMERA_ROLL. Luckily, I have already found out an solution :)